# Reducing a PDE to a dimensionless form with change of variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

I am working through the following example to refresh my memory on how to use the chain rule when changing variables:
[Change of variables (PDE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_variables_(PDE))

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{t}} + S\frac{\partial{V}}{\partial{S}} + \frac{1}{2}S^2\frac{\partial^2{V}}{\partial{S}^2} &=  V \\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

by setting:

$V(S,t) = v(x(S),\tau(t))$

$x(S) = \ln(S)$

$\tau(t) = \frac{1}{2}(T-t)$

$v(x,\tau) = e^{-\frac{1}{2}x - \frac{9}{4}\tau}u(x,\tau)$

Using these I managed to reach to the following stage:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{\tau}}\frac{\partial{\tau}}{\partial{t}} 
+ S \frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{S}}-v + \mbox{the second order term} = 0
\end{split}
\end{equation}

I am unable to follow how to get $\frac{1}{2}S^2\frac{\partial^2{V}}{\partial{S}^2}$ in to the following form: 
$\frac{1}{2}S^2\left(
\frac{\partial^2{x}}{\partial{S^2}}\frac{\partial{v}}{\partial{x}}+
\left(\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{S}}\right)^2\frac{\partial^2{v}}{\partial{x^2}}
\right)$

Could someone please explain how to get the second order term into that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\partial_S = \frac{\partial x}{\partial S}\partial_x = \frac{1}{S}\partial_x
$$
To get second derivitve you apply the above twice so you get
$$
\partial_{SS} = \frac{1}{S}\partial_x\left(\frac{1}{S}\partial_x\right) = -\frac{1}{S^3}\frac{\partial S}{\partial x}\partial_x + \frac{1}{S^2}\partial_{xx} 
$$
Using the first derivarive with $S$ you find that $S^{-1}\partial_xS = 1$ you get
$$
\partial_{SS} = -\frac{1}{S^2}\partial_x + \frac{1}{S^2}\partial_{xx} 
$$

Comment: Where did the minus sign come from in the second equation?

Comment: The full expansion of the derivatives $$\partial_x s^{-1}\partial_x = \partial_x\left(s^{-1}\right) \partial_x + s^{-1}\partial_{xx}$$ the minus comes from taking the derivative of $s^{-1}$.

Comment: If you look at  the result though there is no minus sign involved with that term. So not sure how to arrive to that solution.

Comment: Compute the detivative $$\frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial S^2}$$

Comment: Not a problem. You did the hard part the rest was applying a method with book keeping.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35138/discussion-between-gabor-bakos-and-chinny84).